# react + electron after use ipcMain/ipcRenderer to save data, the page force refresh

Tags: reactjs, electron, ipc

first i have a commpoent such as give your some inputs, after you fill in them and click the save button
then web page send a asyn message to main process and listen to channel. The main process write the datas to files and reply. the file name such as 2023-9-11.json.

If the file doesn't exist, it's normal, but if the file exists, the page is forced to refresh.
**i promise my data is correct**

what happend!

here is my codes.

```
const clickSave = () => {
    if (addlist.length == 1 && addlist[0].text == '') return;
    let params = {
      id: Math.random(),
      title: dayjs().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      progress: 0,
      showDel: false,
      list:
        addlist[addlist.length - 1].text == '' ? addlist.slice(0, -1) : addlist,
    };
    // debugger
    electron.ipcRenderer.send("writeFile", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(params)));
    electron.ipcRenderer.once("onWrite", (event, { status, msg }) => {
      if (status) {
        setAddlist([createaddToList()]);
        getTodoList();
        // debugger;
        return;
      }
    });
  };
```

```
const writeFile = (file, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(file, data, err => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
        return
      }
      resolve('successful')
    })
  })
}
ipcMain.on('writeFile', async (event, arg) => {
  let { title } = arg
  let fileUrl = baseFileUrl(title) + '.json'

  try {
    let { list, progress } = await readFile(fileUrl)
    let arr = [...arg.list, ...list]
    if (progress) {
      let num = Math.round(100 / arr.length)
      list.forEach(item => {
        if (item.checked) {
          arg.progress += num
        }
      })
    }
    arg.list = arr
  } finally {
    try {
      await writeFile(fileUrl, JSON.stringify(arg))
      event.reply('onWrite', { status: true })
    } catch (err) {
      event.reply('onWrite', { status: false, msg: err })
    }
  }

})

ipcMain.on("getFiles", async (event, arg) => {
  let fileUrl = null,
    FileArr = [];
  if (arg) {
    fileUrl = baseFileUrl(arg) + ".json";
    FileArr = [readFile(fileUrl)];
  } else {
    let filesArrName = await readdir(baseFileUrl());
    FileArr = filesArrName.map((item) => readFile(baseFileUrl(item)));
  }
  try {
    let res = await Promise.all(FileArr);
    let handleArr = res.reverse();
    event.reply("getFile", handleArr);
  } catch (err) {}
});
```

I have tried many things, but there is no solution :(